# Why is くせに being used in 「太郎も花子も子供のくせに、口だけは一人前だ」?

Tags: meaning

> 太郎も花子も子供のくせに、口だけは一人前だ。
>
> > Although Taro and Hanako are still only kids, when they talk, they sound like grownups.

As my understanding goes, くせに conveys a negative meaning and, assuming that's the case, I don't see why it's used in the sentence above if both are being described as 一人前. However, 口だけ sounds rough. In other words, couldn't のに be used instead for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation doesn't quite capture the nuance, which may have led to your question. A better translation might be "Taro and Hanako are just kids, but they sure can talk big".

Note that のに is already being employed in the original sentence, just with くせ injected. The のくせに could be replaced with なのに, and the broad meaning would be the same, but it would make the phrase less dismissive of Taro and Hanako being kids. A bit like "are kids" vs "are just kids".